# How to run/manage websites on macOS versions *after* High Sierra?

Tags: server.app, apache, webserver

High Sierra (10.13) is deprecated now that Big Sur (macOS 10.16/11) is out.

High Sierra was the last version of macOS which supported websites (technically Apache, I believe) being managed through the **Server.app** in macOS.

I am now looking for another way to run a 24/7 web server on macOS.

## “Why not use MAMP (Pro) or VirtualHostX (Pro)?”

I have tried both MAMP and VirtualHostX (both regular and pro versions) as possible replacements; however, **neither app is designed for this.** They are designed to be a service for web developers who want to check their web development locally before it is deployed to a remote (usually Linux-based) server.

That is not what I am looking for. I am looking for apps/utilities/tools/whatever to help me configure and run a web server on macOS, ideally compatible with Big Sur.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apache is still installed by default on Mojave at least—I haven't used Catalina extensively. Here's the script I use, although huge warning that I have not tested it on 10.15+, which is why I will not post this as an answer. (I also apologize for readability—I initially wrote this when I was young and stupid, and I wanted to have a one-liner no matter how monstrous the line was!) https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Wowfunhappy/be28b3a05a564ec59bbc814816b14c1f/raw/761f4239379ef9ad548773afea6ca9fb3efa3086/web-sharing.sh

Answer (score -1):

You could run NGINX and Apache via Homebrew on Big Sur as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: My hope is to find something similar to what Server.app, VirtualHostX, or MAMP offers, namely a GUI, rather than having to edit config files manually.